# Vue3 and Vue-Select: How to emit child data to parent when using taggable prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vue-select

I am using the [Vue-Select](https://vue-select.org/) library with Vue3. My objective is to let the user choose tags from an options list and also be able to create new tags if the tags do not exist in the options list.

This works fine in a child component, **but I am having trouble passing/emitting the data up to the parent component.** I need the data in the parent because I am going to package it up for form processing later.

**How can I successfully get the tags from the child component and into the parent component's `formData.tags` property?**

The code [and sandbox link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-jedbya?file=src/components/Parent.vue):

`components/PostEditorTags.vue`:

```
<template>
  <v-select
    :create-option="(tag) => ({ label: tag, value: tag })"
    v-model="selected"
    :options="options"
    multiple
    taggable
    @input="$emit('input', selected)"
    placeholder="add a tag"
  ></v-select>
  <br />
  child component data:
  <pre>{{ selected }}</pre>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import vSelect from 'vue-select';
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';

defineEmits(['input']);

const options = [
  { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
  { value: 'three', label: 'Three' },
  { value: 'four', label: 'Four' },
  { value: 'five', label: 'Five' },
  { value: 'six', label: 'Six' },
  { value: 'seven', label: 'Seven' },
  { value: 'eight', label: 'Eight' },
  { value: 'nine', label: 'Nine' },
  { value: 'ten', label: 'Ten' },
];

let selected = ref([]);
</script>
```

`components/Parent.vue:`

```
<template>
  <h1>Post Tags</h1>
  <PostEditorTags @input="setTagsArr" />
  <br />
  <br />
  parent component data:
  <pre>{{ formData.tags }}</pre>
</template>

<script setup>
import PostEditorTags from './PostEditorTags.vue';

const formData = {
  // title: '',
  // content: '',
  tags: null,
};

function setTagsArr(x) {
  formData.tags = x;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with watcher instead of event

`components/PostEditorTags.vue:`

```js
<template>
  <v-select
    :create-option="(tag) => ({ label: tag, value: tag })"
    v-model="selected"
    :options="options"
    multiple
    taggable
    placeholder="add a tag"
  ></v-select>
  <br />
  child component data:
  <pre>{{ selected }}</pre>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, defineEmits, watch } from 'vue';
import vSelect from 'vue-select';
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';

const options = [{ value: 'one', label: 'One' }, { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }, { value: 'three', label: 'Three' }, { value: 'four', label: 'Four' }, { value: 'five', label: 'Five' }, { value: 'six', label: 'Six' }, { value: 'seven', label: 'Seven' }, { value: 'eight', label: 'Eight' }, { value: 'nine', label: 'Nine' }, { value: 'ten', label: 'Ten' },];

let selected = ref([]);

watch(
  () => selected.value,
  (newValue, oldValue) => {
    act(newValue);
  }
);

const emit = defineEmits(['input'])
const act = (val) => emit('input', val);
</script>
```

Make your data reactive in `components/Parent.vue:`

```
<template>
  <h1>Post Tags</h1>
  <PostEditorTags @input="setTagsArr" />
  <br />
  <br />
  parent component data:
  <pre>{{ formData.tags }}</pre>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import PostEditorTags from './PostEditorTags.vue';

const formData = reactive({
  // title: '',
  // content: '',
  tags: null,
});

function setTagsArr(x) {
  formData.tags = x;
}
</script>
```

**[your demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-xm1kuk)**

Comment: That works! I always have trouble with watchers. Thanks for the help.